# CentOS 7: Can't connect wifi using wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, centos, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I recently got a new wireless card, specifically *Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 WiFi Bluetooth Half Mini Card*. Previously I had been connecting with ethernet so this machine has never been on the wifi.

I've attempted to use `nmcli` to get things working to no avail, so I've fallen back to trying to get everything setup using `wpa_supplicant`.

First things first, I ensure that my interface is up with `ifconfig wlp3s0 up`. Next I attempt to scan for my wireless access point with `iwlist wlp3s0 scanning` which returns:

```
wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 94:10:3E:70:60:FE
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Foobar"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000011eb802d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2005ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0006466F6F626172
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 050400030000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6F181FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1624050000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: BF0C3120C103FAFF0C03FAFF0C03
                    IE: Unknown: C005012A00F0FF
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C336F181FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3424050000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0700E04C02026004
```

I've setup my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file as such:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel

# reading passphrase from stdin
network={
    ssid="Foobar"
    #psk="my-pass-phrase"
    psk=af865233abdc002e9181256fdbc34b81fa956fcf28ac33fd0ec92e25241eb6f3
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=WPA RSN
        pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
```

I try to run wpa_supplicant with `wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlp3s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` which simply returns `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant`.

Output from dmesg returns:

```
[ 1867.954640] wlp3s0: authenticate with 94:10:3e:70:60:fe
[ 1867.957296] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 1/3)
[ 1868.159030] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 2/3)
[ 1868.361207] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 3/3)
[ 1868.562248] wlp3s0: authentication with 94:10:3e:70:60:fe timed out
[ 1882.404522] wlp3s0: authenticate with 94:10:3e:70:60:fe
[ 1882.407019] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 1/3)
[ 1882.608645] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 2/3)
[ 1882.810806] wlp3s0: direct probe to 94:10:3e:70:60:fe (try 3/3)
[ 1883.011897] wlp3s0: authentication with 94:10:3e:70:60:fe timed out
```

Any ideas why I can't connect?

Answer (score 2):

After initializing with wpa supplicant, you'll need to use the DHCP client to request an IP addr like

```
dhclient wlp0... //replace with your interface name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Centos7 myself, I could connect to wifi using

```
 $ nmcli dev wifi list
 *  SSID                      MODE   CHAN  DÉBIT    SIGNAL  BARS  SÉCURITÉ    
    Livebox-3WYX              Infra  1     54 Mo/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA2  
 ...
```

then

```
 $ nmcli --ask dev wifi connect Livebox-3WYX
 Mot de passe : ...
 Périphérique « wlo1 » activé avec « 9c234370-5a39-468d-9b62-202cbc56e9fe ».
```

What error/issue do you get using nmcli to connect your SSID?